# Alternative for Union Optimisation in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to optimize the below query as the transaction logs are getting full on executing the query.

```
insert into db2inst1.FCT_STATIC_DA
select * from db2inst1.FCT_STATIC_DA_AP  union
select * from db2inst1.FCT_STATIC_DA_ASM  union
select * from db2inst1.FCT_STATIC_DA_BHR  union
select * from db2inst1.FCT_STATIC_DA_CHN  union
select * from db2inst1.FCT_STATIC_DA_DEL  union
select * from db2inst1.FCT_STATIC_DA_GUJ  union
select * from db2inst1.FCT_STATIC_DA_HAR  union
select * from db2inst1.FCT_STATIC_DA_HP  union
select * from db2inst1.FCT_STATIC_DA_JK  union
select * from db2inst1.FCT_STATIC_DA_KER  union
select * from db2inst1.FCT_STATIC_DA_KK  union
select * from db2inst1.FCT_STATIC_DA_KOL  union
select * from db2inst1.FCT_STATIC_DA_MAH  union
select * from db2inst1.FCT_STATIC_DA_MP  union
select * from db2inst1.FCT_STATIC_DA_MUM  union
select * from db2inst1.FCT_STATIC_DA_NE  union
select * from db2inst1.FCT_STATIC_DA_ORS  union
select * from db2inst1.FCT_STATIC_DA_PB  union
select * from db2inst1.FCT_STATIC_DA_RAJ  union
select * from db2inst1.FCT_STATIC_DA_TN  union
select * from db2inst1.FCT_STATIC_DA_UPE  union
select * from db2inst1.FCT_STATIC_DA_UPW  union
select * from db2inst1.FCT_STATIC_DA_WB
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do one INSERT per table instead, to keep transaction size down. (This will not remove duplicates as UNION does.)

Comment: thanks for your response !!!!!!!!!!!! But how can I remove duplicates. Please help.

Comment: Do `INSERT ... SELECT DISTINCT ...`, to remove duplicates per source table. Do you have duplicates spread over several tables?